# can not create a maven archetype project, the progress bar get stuck in 33%

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I installed Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)
Build id: 20220908-1902
It includes already maven, and I have tried to create some maven archetype projects, but without success, always get stuck in the progress bar.
Anyone has some clues? Thank you!

[image: can not create a maven archetype project, the progress bar get stuck in 33%]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I had this too, it took me a long time to spot the very simple fix.  If you look in the console you'll see that the maven project generation is in interactive mode.  You just need to click Y (yes) in the console to confirm that you are happy with the configuration and it will finish.

Comment: OMG - Thank You!  I was pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.

Comment: Wow, brilliant. What a bad UX. One thing: I had to press `Enter` (which accepts the default "Y" value). There doesn't seem to be anywhere where I can "click Y".

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on Y, 
typing "Y and then hit enter" worked for me.
Thanks for saving time.

Answer (score 12):

Just need to enter Y  in Console and press enter. Refer to snapshot for more details

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Your answer seems to be helpful, but the question already has a similar accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to go to the console and press Enter on your keyboard !

Answer (score 3):

You just need to click Y (yes) in the console to confirm

Comment: This could be a comment

Answer (score 3):

I was stucking on that and I was thinking to learn another framework :|. Just need to click Y and press enter.

groupId: com.myMaven artifactId: FirstProjectMaven version:
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT package: com.myMaven.FirstProjectMaven  Y: : Y

Answer (score 2):

Typing 'y' resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this was a very tricky thing.

As already mentioned by others, you need to type Y in the console and press enter. Then the wizard will continue and complete the action.

Alternatively, you can get rid of this issue by simply unchecking the checkbox as shown below:

[image: Eclipse Screen]

Answer (score 0):

This could be wrong version for MacOS ARM architecture (M1 chip):
Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0) Build id: 20220908-1902

Is this Mac book of M1 chip or Intel? I had the same issue with the same version on my Mac book with M1 chip.
I installed the right eclipse version from "https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/" --> choose "AArch64"

direct link:
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2022-09/R/eclipse-inst-jre-mac-aarch64.dmg